# PHPUnit Test: issue with write into / retrieve from Memcached

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I use Laravel version 6.20.31 and in my PHPUnit test I can't store or retrieve data using Memcached.

I updated CACHE_DRIVER to value "memcached" in phpunit.xml:

```
...snip...
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="memcached"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <php>
```

In my PHPUnit test:

```
Cache::store('memcached')->put('foo', 'bar');
\Log::debug(cache()->getMemcached()->getAllKeys()); // should return an array with all keys stored in Memcached but array is empty
```

Is it not possible to use Memcached within PHPUnit tests?
Or do I have to configure it properly?

UPDATE:

`dd(config('cache.stores.memcached')`
returns

```
.^ array:5 [
  "driver" => "memcached"
  "persistent_id" => "bbsip"
  "sasl" => array:2 [
    0 => null
    1 => null
  ]
  "options" => []
  "servers" => array:1 [
    0 => array:3 [
      "host" => "127.0.0.1"
      "port" => "11211"
      "weight" => 100
    ]
  ]
]
```

My config/cache.php

```
...snip...
        'memcached' => [
            'driver' => 'memcached',
            'persistent_id' => env('MEMCACHED_PERSISTENT_ID'),
            'sasl' => [
                env('MEMCACHED_USERNAME'),
                env('MEMCACHED_PASSWORD'),
            ],
            'options' => [
                // Memcached::OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT  => 2000,
            ],
            'servers' => [
                [
                    'host' => env('MEMCACHED_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
                    'port' => env('MEMCACHED_PORT', 11211),
                    'weight' => 100,
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

UPDATE 2:
I'd like to use specifically Memcached within PHPUnit because the test should cover a feature that stores data in Memcached (within the application Memcached works perfectly fine).

Comment: If you try to dump (`dd(config('cache.memcached')`), what do you get back? See this is the [original configuration]  (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/ecf460a874e5943c1063ef9585bc7491ead15b0a/config/cache.php#L55-L72), are those `ENV` populated when the test is running?

Comment: @matiaslauriti dd(config('cache.memcached')); returns null. Do I have to configure it specifically for PHPUnit? How? Within application-context Memcached works perfectly fine.

Comment: I am sorry, the right config is `config('cache.stores.memcached')`, my bad! Quick update too: it doesn't matter if you are using Memcached, Redis or database, it will work either way as you are only selecting a driver, you do not have to test if memcache works (you should be using `CACHE_DRIVER=array` because you do not even need a service when running tests), you are testing the framework in that case (testing that `Cache` facade or `cache` helper works as expected and that is already tested by the framework)...

Comment: no problem, I updated my post with the return (not empty array). Thanks for helping me debug!

Comment: Check my comment again, I have updated the comment but I think you did not see the update. You should not need to "test" the cache as that is a framework/driver issue (it is already tested and working).

Comment: Ok, I see that testing Memcached functionality isn't necessary. I have a feature that uses Memcached and I'd like to test this feature. Within the PHPUnit test I can't store and therefor retrieve using Memcached and the feature fails.

Comment: have you a memcache instance at 127.0.0.1 with user/pass null/null?

Comment: yes, Memcached default installation on localhost doesn't need authorization afaik.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason using cache-helper like

```
cache()->getMemcached()->getAllKeys();
```

returns empty array but static methods like this

```
Cache::store('memcached')->get('foo'));
```

works as expected and returns value of key 'foo'.